# Place quotes & add comma around many items in WHERE

Tags: sql-server, insert, where-in

I have a very long list of codes for a WHERE statement in SQL Server that I would like to 'quickly' add quotes around each one and a comma at end of each one.

I would like to take the huge list like this (with 100's of them in my WHERE)

```
WHERE CODE IN 
(P279273
Q2793567
Q29262718)
```

and 'quickly' insert quotes and commas like this (doing it directly in SQL)

```
WHERE CODE IN
('P279273',
'Q2793567',
'Q29262718')
```

Anyone know how to insert those in quickly in SQL Server directly without manually going line by line (and not doing it in Excel first)?

Comment: Your favourite text editor plus a macro?

Comment: search and replace in a text editor? (i.e. search for a new line char and replace it with ',\n' (then manually edit the first and last lines)

Comment: You could do that in SSMS it has the opton  for regex in the search/replace, search for \n and \r and replace with the additional quotes / commas

Comment: Allocate your long string to a variable, `string_split` into a temp table, then join on the table instead of using `in`.

Comment: @STU - are you able to 'type out' a quick example for me on how to use your suggestion in SQL?  I'm very visual when it comes to learning in SQL.

Comment: I usually dump it out to excel then concat on the apostrophe's and commas then copy back to note pad and then copy from there into the SQL window.  Excel formula fill down takes all of 30 seconds in my book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another option

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'P279273
Q2793567
Q29262718
Q99999
Q00000
'

Select string_agg(v,',')
 From (
        Select v=concat('''',replace(value,char(13),''),'''')
         From string_split(@S,char(10))
         where value<>''
      ) A
```

**Results**

```
'P279273','Q2793567','Q29262718','Q99999','Q00000'
```

Comment: Thanks John - I got it to work - it was limited to 100 rows though - but I am glad to have learned that for smaller lists - thanks very much!

Comment: @KLR Had no idea there was a limit.   Just for fun I will test.   Always happy to help

Comment: @KLR  FYI I just tested for 500 lines.  No issue or limit

Comment: ok!  thanks for checking.  I'm not sure why I'm limited here.

Answer (score 0):

First get a line-separated list of your elements.

1. If you use visual studio code/azure data studio, you can use `Ctrl + Alt` (`Shift + Alt` for Visual Studio/SSMS) and `down arrow` to make multiple cursors for each line.
2. Once you see a cursor for each line, insert your single quote.
3. Hold `Ctrl` and press the `right arrow` (or `End` if one or more lines has spaces in the words) to move to the right side of the keyword. Insert another single quote and a comma.
4. Delete the comma on the last line. Cut and paste the list into your `WHERE IN ()`

Article on this - https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/quick-tip-quickly-bulk-edit-lines-in-ssms

Comment: I tried this (I'm in SSMS) - I tried SHIFT + ALT with down arrow but it would only put the quotes and comma on the 'one line' I was on...

Comment: Are you holding the Shift + Alt while pressing Down? I just tried this in SSMS myself just now and it works. I also have the basic keybinds. You have to hold Shift + Alt and press the down arrow for each line.

Comment: Here’s a graphic of what it looks like as well as a small article https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/quick-tip-quickly-bulk-edit-lines-in-ssms

Comment: oh that would take too long (shift + alt + down arrow) - there are 1000's of lines.  Thanks though!